# Is Scala set equivalent to a predicate function?

Tags: scala

How can a set be acceptable argument to a filter function?

```
scala> val v1 = Set(1,2,3)
v1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

scala> val v2 = Set(2,3,4)
v2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(2, 3, 4)

scala> v1 filter v2
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scala.collection.Set[A]` extends `A => Boolean` – in Scala, a set *is* a function.

Similarly, `Map[A, B]` extends `A => B` and `List[A]` extends `Int => A`.

Answer (score 2):

Huw [said it correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29247601/238884): a set is a function.

The Set maps every value of its type to a Boolean, `true` meaning "Yes, I contain that value" and `false` meaning "No, I don't."

Similarly, a Map takes values of key type and returns value of its value type; a List takes integers and return the element at that index.

This is not a peculiarity of Scala, this is a legitimate interpretation of the meanings of Set, Map, and List.

Interesting, the domain of the Set function (the "legal" inputs) is all values of the type, whereas with Map and List only a subset of values are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/sets.html

The apply method for a set is the same as contains. So set(elem) is the same as set contains elem.

```
v1 filter {x => v2.contains(x)}
~ v1 filter {v2.contains(_)}
~ v1 filter {v2.apply(_)}
~ v1 filter v2
```